# Logical operators in constrained optimization

Tags: optimization, constraints

Trying to find the minimum of a function $f(x,y,z)$ is it possible to write (and solve) such constraints:
$min f(x,y,z)$
subject to $(x=1 \land y=4 \land z=2) \lor (x=4 \land y=1 \land z=3) \lor (x=9 \land y=7 \land z=6)$
If it is possible, which method can be used for it? Is it even feasible for e.g. 100k of such or statements?
Surely I could calculate $f(x,y,z)$ for all the 100k combinations and pick the minimum, but this doesn't scale very well, is there a more performant way, even if it's an approximation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused about this question. Is the answer to your question: "Yes, it is the minimum of the values $\{ f(1,4,2), f(4,1,3), f(9,7,6)\}$"? Also are $b$ and $c$ the same as $y$ and $z$? If your question was not answered by the first statement, perhaps consider expanding and clarifying your question.

Comment: sorry I edited the question. $y$ and $z$ were meant

Comment: Look up SAT. SAT is NP-Complete. An optimization problem can be converted into a sequence of SAT problems. Also, look at integer programming.

Comment: $y=4=1$ What system are you working in which allows this?

Comment: I've edited it again. @copper.hat will look into it

Comment: Huh? What will I look into?

Comment: @copper.hat lol

Comment: I will look into it, was what I meant and thanks. So it is possible to formulate such constraints in integer programming?

Comment: Yes, it is integer programming representable, typically through so called big-M modelling